# why $D\setminus f(D)$ is open?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is C-analytic in $D(0; 1)$ and maps the unit circle into itself. Show then that $f$ maps the
entire disc onto itself.

**My attempt** :  I  got the  answer  given below but i have  some confusion in the given below answer  mark in red box

[image]

**My doubt**: why $D\setminus f(D)$ is open ?

**My thinking** : Here $D(0,1)=D$ is an open disk and $f(D)$  is also open since contnious image of open is open . But this will contradicts the theorem **complement of open set is closed** because $f(D)$ is not closed

I think it may be $D\setminus f(D)$$=$ (open) $-$(open)$=$ open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0<r<1-|w|$. Then the disk of radius $r$ around $w$ is contained in $D\setminus f(D)$ because if $\zeta $ is in this disk then $|f(z)-\zeta| \geq |f(z)-w|-|w-\zeta| >1-|w| -r >0$ (so $f(z) \neq w$). We have proved that any point $w$ of $D\setminus f(D)$ is an interior point.

Comment: ..@Kavi  sir  i have some confusion in ur last sentence **We have proved that any point $w$ of $D\setminus f(D)$ is an interior point**  

Are  u mean to say that any point of  disc $D(w,r)$ is an interior point of $D\setminus f(D)?$ yes or no

Comment: @jasmine Saying that $w$ is an interior point of  a set $A$ is equivalent to saying that some open disk around $w$ is contained in $A$.

Comment: oks got its @Kavi sir