# why $|f(z)-w| \ge 1-|w|$ give open set to $D\setminus f(D)?$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic in the unit disc $D(0,1)$ and maps the unit circle into itself. Show then that $f$ maps the entire disc onto itself.

My attempt : I got the  answer  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116965/show-that-f-maps-the-entire-unit-disc-onto-itself?rq=1)

But i have some confusion in the given below answer marked in $\color{red}{red \  box}$ [image]

**My thinking**: definition  of open set say that  $B(x,\epsilon) \subset A \subset X$  for every $x\in A$

in the given answer  its say that  $|f(z)-w| \ge 1-|w|$

from the open set definition  we have  $B(x,r)= \{y\in D(0,1) | d(x,y) < r\}$

Now  take $A= D \setminus f(D),$

$r= 1-|w|$,$y= f(z)$ and $x=w$

for open set we must have  $ d(x,y) =|y-x|< r $

But **given answer**  show that $|y-x|\ge r$ so it can not be open
i,e $D\setminus f(D)$ cannot be open

**My doubt**: why $|f(z)-w| \ge 1-|w|$ give  open set to  $D\setminus f(D)?$

Comment: $1-|w|>0$ so you proof that if $w\in \mathbb{D}-f(\mathbb{D})$ then $B(w,1-|w|)\subset  \mathbb{D}-f(\mathbb{D})$ so this is are a open subset of $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: okks @Zhooo i have confusion  in $|f(z)-w| \ge 1-|w|$  . I thinks  it  should be  like $|f(z)-w| < 1-|w|$ then we can claim that $ D \setminus f(D)$ is an open set

Comment: You asked this before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3915417/42969

Comment: yes@MartinR but  i could not able to understand the   logics behind  $ |f(z) -w| \ge 1-|w|$ give an open set

Comment: We want to show that $\mathbb{D}-f(\mathbb{D})$ is open, my claim is that $B(w,1-|w|)\subset \mathbb{D}-f(\mathbb{D})$ if $w \in \mathbb{D}-f(\mathbb{D})$ this proof that this set is open so, take $v\in B(w,1-|w|)$ then if $v=f(z)$ for some $z\in \mathbb{D}$ then $|f(z)-w|=|v-w|<1-|w|$ but this is a contradiction with your inequality.

Comment: oks @Zhooo $v \in B( w, 1-|w|)$  that  mean  we can take $ v= 1 -\frac{|w|}{2} $

now $|1 -\frac{|w|}{2}-w| < 1-|w|$ i think it will not give contradiction...

Comment: @Zhooo u mean $| f(z) -w| < 1-|w| \le |f(z)-w|$  that is $| f(z)-w| < |f(z) -w|$ give contradiction  am i right ?

Comment: Yes, this inequality is the contradiction.

Comment: oks  thanks  a lots @Zhooo now  got its